# AngularJS ng-options not working empty select boxes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

i'm developing an app that should have 4 select boxes populated, from json getting from a function through the `$http` directive, with the ng-options and ng-filter directive.

The problem is that i've no errors in the console but the select is always empty.

This is an example of a portion of json array that the app getting of:

```
[{"sede":"Poser Hairdressing","professionista":"Lavorante  2","day":"2017-07-31","time":"15:00"},{"sede":"Poser Hairdressing","professionista":"Lavorante  2","day":"2017-07-31","time":"15:30"}]
```

And this is my code:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
   app.controller("myCtrl", function($http, $scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    console.log("JavaScript Function");
    var firstName = "John";
    var lastName = "Doe";
    $scope.submit = function() {
     console.log("Submit");
    }
    var attivita = <?php echo json_encode($cod_attivita); ?>;
    var config = {
      transformResponse: function (data, headers) {
     var result = {
       events: [],
       events2: [],
       events3: [],
       schedules: [],
       schedules2: [],
       schedules3: []
     };
          console.log(data);
     var events = JSON.parse(data);
     console.log(events);
     var events2 = JSON.parse(data);
     var events3 = JSON.parse(data);
     var dates = [];
     var sedi = [];
     var professionisti = [];
     console.log("qua3");
     for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
       if (dates.indexOf(events[i].day) === -1) {
      var date = events[i].day;
      dates.push(date);
      result.events.push({
        date: date
      });
       }
       if (sedi.indexOf(events[i].sede) === -1) {
      var sede = events[i].sede;
      sedi.push(sede);
      result.events2.push({
        sede: sede
      });
       }
       if (professionisti.indexOf(events[i].professionista) === -1) {
      var professionista = events[i].professionista;
      professionisti.push(professionista);
      result.events3.push({
        professionista: professionista
      });
       }
       var a = 0;
       var found = false;
       while (a < result.schedules2.length) {
        if (events[i].sede === result.schedules2[a].sede && events[i].professionista === result.schedules2[a].professionista) {
         found = true;
        }
        a++;
       }
       if (found == false) {
        result.schedules2.push({
       sede: events[i].sede,
       professionista: events[i].professionista
        });
       }
       var a = 0;
       var found = false;
       while (a < result.schedules3.length) {
        if (events[i].sede === result.schedules3[a].sede && events[i].professionista === result.schedules3[a].professionista && events[i].day === result.schedules3[a].date) {
         found = true;
        }
        a++;
       }
       if (found == false) {
        console.log("OLEE");
        result.schedules3.push({
       sede: events[i].sede,
       professionista: events[i].professionista,
       date: events[i].day
        });
       }
       result.schedules.push({
      sede: events[i].sede,
      professionista: events[i].professionista,
      date: events[i].day,
      time: events[i].time
      //console.log("qua4");
       });
     }
     console.log(result);
     return result;
      }
    };
    var email = "assistenza@pgdue.com";
    var link = 'http://sviluppo.pgdue.com/shuttle/admin/app-service/get-orari?e='+email+"&attivita="+attivita;
    console.log(link);
    return $http.get(link, config)
      .then(getEventsCompleted)
      .catch(getEventsFailed);
    function getEventsCompleted(response) {
     console.log(response.data);
      return response.data;
      console.log(response.data);
    }
    
    function getEventsFailed(error) {
      console.error(error);
    } 
   });
```

```html
<div ng-app="App">
    <div align="center" ng-controller="TimesController as ctrl">
        <p style="font-size: 22px;">Inserisci appuntamento</p>
        <br>
        <div class="list" align="center">
                <div class="input-label">
                </div>
                <select style="width: 75%;" ng-options="event as event.sede for event in ctrl.data.events2" ng-model="ctrl.form.sede">
                    <option value="" disabled>Seleziona sede</option>
                </select>
        </div><br>
        <div class="list" align="center">
                <div class="input-label">
                </div>
                <select style="width: 75%;" ng-options="schedule as schedule.professionista for schedule in ctrl.data.schedules2| filter: { sede: ctrl.form.sede.sede}" ng-model="ctrl.form.professionista" ng-disabled="!ctrl.form.sede">
                    <option value="" disabled>Seleziona professionista</option>
                </select>
        </div><br>
        <div class="list" align="center">
                <div class="input-label">
                </div>
                <select style="width: 75%;" ng-options="schedule as schedule.date for schedule in ctrl.data.schedules3| filter: { professionista: ctrl.form.professionista.professionista, sede: ctrl.form.sede.sede}" ng-model="ctrl.form.giorno" ng-disabled="!ctrl.form.professionista">
                    <option value="" disabled>Seleziona giorno</option>
                </select>
        </div><br>
        <div class="list" align="center">
                <div class="input-label">
                </div>
                <select style="width: 75%;" ng-options="schedule as schedule.time for schedule in ctrl.data.schedules| filter: { date: ctrl.form.giorno.date, professionista: ctrl.form.professionista.professionista, sede: ctrl.form.sede.sede}" ng-model="ctrl.form.ora" ng-disabled="!ctrl.form.giorno">
                    <option value="" disabled>Seleziona orario</option>
                </select>
        </div><br>
    </div>
</div>
<br>                    
<div align="right">
    <button ng-click="ctrl.submit()"><p>Prenota</p></button>
</div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Can someone help me?

Thank's

Comment: You need to explicitly set default value using ng-options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-options="event as event.sede for event in option1" ng-model="selected" ng-change="myfunctn()">
                    <option value="" disabled>Seleziona sede</option>
                </select>

</div>

</body>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.option1 = [{"sede":"Poser Hairdressing","professionista":"Lavorante  2","day":"2017-07-31","time":"15:00"},
      ]
      
 $scope.myfunctn = function(){
 console.log($scope.selected)
 }
     
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: yes but my problem is that should be other options getting from the controller with the ng-options directive but there aren't

Comment: so for the first select should be two options, the first is "Seleziona sede" that is disabled and an option that should be "Poser Hairdressing" that is getting from controller (example of json array that i wrote in the question)

Comment: I have updated my answer @Edoardo, can you please check

Answer (score 1):

Try this. hope it will work for you.

```
    <select 
      ng-options="x as x.sede for x in option1 track by x.sede"
      ng-model="selected" 
      ng-change="myfunctn()">
       <option value="" >Seleziona sede</option>
     </select>
```

see example [in plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/JaIaSXXfrAeGKUIechIa?p=preview)

Comment: remember if you want to use object in ng-option always use **track by** clause to set value in option list.